# Este método de eliminar al final de la lista simple no elimina al ultimo

Tags: java

En el método eliminar al final cuando realizo la prueba me muestra el elemento a eliminar pero no lo elimina al final me muestra la lista con todos los elementos no elimina nada y no se por que no los elimina

```
public class ListaSimple<E> implements Lista<E>, Serializable {
    
        protected NodoSimple<E> nodoInicial;
        protected NodoSimple<E> nodoFinal;
    
       
       
        public E eliminarAlFinal(){
            if(estaVacia()){
            //Caso Lista Vacia
            return null;
            }
            else{
            //caso lista con elemento
            E datos = nodoFinal.dato;
            System.out.println("NOdo "+nodoFinal.anterior);
            nodoFinal.anterior = nodoFinal ;
            nodoFinal= nodoFinal.anterior;
            
            System.out.println("NOdo2 "+nodoFinal);
            
            return datos;
            
            }
```

Comment: Por el código entiendo que estas utilizando una lista enlazada pero no queda claro si es una lista enlazada simple (cada nodo apunta al siguiente) o doblemente enlazada (cada nodo apunta al anterior y al siguiente). En cualquier caso, revisa bien el código. Entiendo que lo que intentas hacer es que el penúltimo elemento ya no apunte al siguiente y sea el nodo final. En alguna parte del código deberías hacer que el penúltimo elemento `nodoFinal.anterior` ya no apunte al siguiente. Si fuera una lista doblemente enlazada sería algo así `nodoFinal.anterior.siguiente = null`

Comment: es una lista simple (cada nodo apunta al siguiente)

Comment: Sin embargo el atributo se llama `anterior`, es confuso. Si es una lista enlazada simple, tendrás que recorrerla entera hasta llegar al penúltimo elemento, el que cumple la condición `nodo.siguiente == nodoFinal`, y una vez encontrado el nodo quitarle la referencia al nodo siguiente `nodo.siguiente = null` y hacer que ese sea el nodo final `nodoFinal = nodo`.